# How to work around or to remedy Error: Invalid Use of Null?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

In this piece of MS Access Code I am trying to get the MAX Date of a Customer signup. First I have to convert the date so it can work with an aggregate function. Unfortunately there are areas in the date column that are null.

I am getting the error *Invalid use of null* due to some records missing dates.

How can I remedy that, is there a work around?

Here is the code:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.FIRST_NAME, 
    MAX(DateSerial(CInt(Left([CUSTOMER.SIGNUP_DATE],4)),CInt(Mid([CUSTOMER.SIGNUP_DATE],5,2)),CInt(Right([CUSTOMER.SIGNUP_DATE],2)))) AS SIGN_DATE, 
    (DateSerial(CInt(Left([CUSTOMER.LEAVE_DATE],4)),CInt(Mid([CUSTOMER.LEAVE_DATE],5,2)),CInt(Right([CUSTOMER.LEAVE_DATE],2)))) AS LEV_DATE
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE ((DateSerial(CInt(Left([CUSTOMER.SIGNUP_DATE],4)),CInt(Mid([CUSTOMER.SIGNUP_DATE],5,2)),CInt(Right([CUSTOMER.SIGNUP_DATE],2)))) <=Date())
    AND ((DateSerial(CInt(Left([CUSTOMER.LEAVE_DATE],4)),CInt(Mid([CUSTOMER.LEAVE_DATE],5,2)),CInt(Right([CUSTOMER.LEAVE_DATE],2)))) =#012/31/2012#)
GROUP BY
    CUSTOMER.FIRST_NAME,
    CUSTOMER.SIGNUP_DATE,
    CUSTOMER.LEAVE_DATE;
```

Comment: Suggestion: create a VIEW, say named `CurrentCustomers` that filters out customers with a null `LEAVE_DATE` then target the VIEW. But you really ought to permanently replace those text-as-dates columns with actual temporal values rather than try to do this on the fly.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about first filtering out the null than adding the Aggregate, the tables are linked to Access and so I have to convert their text values to date.

Comment: Does it work correctly when you enclose the names in brackets like that? Shouldn't e.g. `[CUSTOMER.SIGNUP_DATE]` be `[CUSTOMER].[SIGNUP_DATE]` instead? I'm not an MS Access person, so please excuse me if it seems a silly question.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I did try that but same error.

Answer (score 1):

Your SIGNUP_DATE field contains dates as strings in this format: "20120131".  So you're using Left(), Mid(), and Right() functions to split out the year, month, and day substrings, converting them to numbers with CInt() and finally feeding those numbers to DateSerial().

If only your date string included suitable delimiters between the 3 parts, you could simply feed the string to CDate(), for example CDate("2012-01-31").  So I propose you add delimiters to the string in a query and feed that to CDate().

Here is my simplified CUSTOMERS table:

```
id SIGNUP_DATE
1  20120130
2 
3  20120131
```

This query transforms the non-Null SIGNUP_DATE values to Date/Time values and discards rows where SIGNUP_DATE is Null (the row with id=2 is excluded).

```
SELECT
    id,
    CDate(Left(SIGNUP_DATE,4) & "-"
        & Mid(SIGNUP_DATE,5,2) & "-" &
        Right(SIGNUP_DATE,2))
        AS SIGN_DATE
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE SIGNUP_DATE Is Not Null;
```

Then getting the Max value is simple.

```
SELECT Max(q.SIGN_DATE) AS MaxOfSIGN_DATE
FROM (
        SELECT
            id,
            CDate(Left(SIGNUP_DATE,4) & "-"
                & Mid(SIGNUP_DATE,5,2) & "-" &
                Right(SIGNUP_DATE,2))
                AS SIGN_DATE
        FROM CUSTOMER
        WHERE SIGNUP_DATE Is Not Null
    ) AS q;
```

**Edit**: With no sample data to test against, I'll just wing it and suggest you try this query:

```
SELECT
    q.FIRST_NAME,
    #2012/12/31# AS LEV_DATE,
    Max(q.SIGN_DATE) AS MaxOfSIGN_DATE
FROM (
        SELECT
            FIRST_NAME,
            CDate(Left(SIGNUP_DATE,4) & "-"
                & Mid(SIGNUP_DATE,5,2) & "-" &
                Right(SIGNUP_DATE,2))
                AS SIGN_DATE
        FROM CUSTOMER
        WHERE
            SIGNUP_DATE Is Not Null
            AND LEAVE_DATE = "20121231"
    ) AS q
GROUP BY
    1,
    2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the very valuable input! For the MAX function I am not trying to select the CUSTOMER with the highest date. I am trying to select the Highest Signup date if a customer has more then one. Lets say if a Customer has two dates. 01/01/2012 and 01/02/2012, then I want the highest, your code gives me the highest date in the entire column.

Comment: Yes, I presented it that way because it was easy for me to do.  Use the same principles and apply them in your original GROUP BY query --- compute the Max() for each of your groups rather than only once for the full recordset returned by the query.

Comment: Yes, records are only pickup if those dates values are there. Originally, the entire idea of the MAX was to get the highest dates. That's when I got the null error. But The records can be skipped.
It's a very simple query. If it's null skip it, get the highest date.
Yes LEAVE_DATE could stay that way, remember, I was creating anomalies to learn from.